# Additive basis of order $2$ (I)

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Can we find $\alpha>1$ such that $u=(\lfloor n^\alpha\rfloor)_{n\geqslant0}$ is an additive basis of order $2$ (i.e. $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}, \exists(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}^2, x=u_n+u_m$) ?

**Update** : I crossposted to **[MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304535/additive-basis-of-order-2)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $1<\alpha<\frac32$, $(\lfloor n^{\alpha}\rfloor)_{n\geqslant0}$ is an asymptotic basis of order 2.
I found these two articles :

J-M. Deshouillers, [**Un problème binaire en théorie additive**](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa25/aa2549.pdf), Acta Arith. 25 (1974), 393-403

S.V. Konyagin, [**An additive problem with fractional powers**](http://cds.cern.ch/record/720991/files/sis-2004-086.ps), Mathematical Notes, 2003, 73:4, 594–597