# Additive basis of order $2$ (II)

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Can we find, **using elementary ways**, an additive basis of order $2$, $(u_n)_{n\geqslant1}$, such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(u_{n+1}-u_n)=+\infty$ ?

If $\alpha\in\left]1,\frac32\right[$, the sequence $\left(\lfloor n^{\alpha}\rfloor\right)$ works (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838191/additive-basis-of-order-2)), but the proof is a little complicated for me...

Comment: I don't think it even exists.

Comment: I am not sure what you want in here: Is it about "Given $u_n$ with the condition, any natural number $m$ is expressed as a sum of $u_k+u_l$?"

Comment: Also, I'd like to know why you think your question (I) does not answer (II).

Comment: Yes, my question was not clear. I fixed it.

Comment: Similar to Goldbach's conjecture would be something like if $\ \left\{\left\lfloor \frac{1}{2} n\log n \right \rfloor \right\}\ $ is an additive basis of order two. I don't know what the status of such a conjecture is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found this article : **[Cassels bases](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.3144.pdf)** (cf. Theorem 6, p. 11).