# How sparse/"thin" (asymptotically) can additive bases of order $2$ be?

Tags: number-theory, additive-combinatorics, combinatorial-number-theory

A subset $B$ is called an (asymptotic) additive basis of order $2$ if every sufficiently large natural number $n$ can be written as the sum of at most $2$ elements of $B.$

> How small/sparse can such sets be asymptotically?

So for example, let $b_n$ be the $n-th$ element of $B$, when $B$ is written as an increasing sequence of integers, rather than a set. Do we have, for example:

$$\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{n^2} = 0\ ? $$

Are there any known good upper bounds of $O(b_n)?\ $

I came up with this question while thinking about the Goldbach conjecture, and this led me to read wikipedia's articles on [Erdős–Turán conjecture on additive bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Tur%C3%A1n_conjecture_on_additive_bases), although I believe my question is tangential. [Sidon sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence) may also be relevant.

Edit: [relevant question $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838191/additive-basis-of-order-2-i?rq=1) $\qquad$
[Relevant question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846506/additive-basis-of-order-2-ii?noredirect=1&lq=1)

"Thin basis" definition found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X12001410):

> The set $A$ of nonnegative integers is called a basis of order $h$ if
> every nonnegative integer can be represented as the sum of exactly $h$
> not necessarily distinct elements of $A$. An additive basis $A$ of
> order $h$ is called thin if there exists $c>0$ such that the number of
> elements of $A$ not exceeding $x$ is less than $xc^{1/h}$ for all
> $x\geq 1.$

[This paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272482/1-s2.0-S0022314X00X0011X/1-s2.0-S0022314X00925678/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDpnttLPebis%2FPOKvlO1mm8THCofDMwarrL1IiLt2u%2BGgIhANml8Z2rC99W5nXXX466CPLOvabFHvn3lcDazL70ZNUDKrMFCEMQBRoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgzPX6jM3az7Kig%2Fo4IqkAWEoF1BdsOBImmMACO2Anh4pkd%2FjyKqie3Ste8kbhnE7vinzlmxH4Y8bm5EurwouNZbqMef6SGteszLnxgUtGE%2BZLXC%2BrnErrL4RXgkZIYkYufcNpvBsznV4EvvRqMqVUhVcGzQ5Gupidzsz5X4cHXpJYOvRY7Ql0258GnrLv08hkkokLhRpyHAldlM0ogVES3Y3XDziky9vrPq2wfugUMCnLHSp9pa%2BABmDBzKIEEsIc0A5wJaT81nS6dTVNeHwPx7RE5OImKyGNzoMgoFeAE7hHzorvzFEgCTUgD7Yj8foAgM%2Bu0MDW%2FJbqTxsudg3rhVIdrU%2Fzcege5AiqCAvBm3rMaRiPAcC9ELHgf7zjXRUbLbIlYw3MCa0yZ4Uoh2n9pAq6IYZ6cvDiDfnkf4sceTFbUm40dVa%2FPeWjJGnijdLEWm0ygwvWjbqcXcQHu%2FKhG%2FfWMUhHIC82j%2BBjAEpf2G77o4siB1dhZwVZOr47%2FIaD3eHe9lpD8rEVC5ciIxwlVOGqZXjlbe3cycjkkemKtXR7tkzvbGhj2sq6ITMUdUj6n1vhHUCw1g987KYoWCApAbsxmBHoULtPfx3cGVuAbwv%2BiKiOjGrgelZePiDGeOzeH65m%2Bf91r8ciXOFW4m3SvX2mxGxzemWuFBId6MjK7TCoKsfbKCWKf9A8doyI1696QngTZi8TiyUhKAhk2ZAbx6IHtqn%2FYKuwLJSv%2F0XXrW4UA%2FoUQgMZRL4kAOoqhq1n3uMlQQ8Wkl6QcXMJ4u97e%2B%2B325hUrAqygYLW3R87dYzZOBCyYLTelfHnp88FbrmyLRkfTAR%2FGmuGtB01mqhksRK8TzFLcdYyeFDDtSzUxUXJ5Show8eBCPH1tufaUC7zCEpZqlBjqwATDiF5%2BL5gGyZlt0SYpJNAkgvTduGGFhcLnLJGPTueo1A0ojMMn7Ngo67yNmpxL8uIOP%2BMZG37kgc5pqdJwM1vk17UszQE3Jdykyl81%2BWSoQVbFfDYGsW9LluuvJ9It9zGBPh%2BZ335oC5%2BYpI0y54eXOprnnaEPMDx4ufwjoL8BRCqcLz%2FuvmgXyGYfHLdWOGIOL9Tw3HFjbyb2BNS35Js%2BkyA2L0lWx9T%2FdlVWVgTqA&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230706T110048Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYW723CIEJ%2F20230706%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=ddd400b0a89882b2659929b209cbe1763a975dd366632251a3e11ecb3e6a6a02&hash=943786e0b83cf4524c27e8d624717ad63d591b14ccf309966945571d785db9cd&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022314X00925678&tid=spdf-6798538f-dc38-4c57-a4ca-8b58b298cacd&sid=14ba518f40cf6240a11a4ee91f3e59b7863cgxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=010051015759545d595a&rr=7e275898fc232fdd&cc=gb) shows how to construct sets such that $O(b_n) = n^2.$

Am I right then in thinking this is the best upper bound for $O(b_n)$ asymptotically? For example, we can make a similar argument [to this simple counting/combinatorial one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4701996/29156) to conclude that $O(b_n) = n^3$ is impossible?