# How to show $A_x:= \{ \left\lfloor x^n\right\rfloor:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is **not** an additive basis (of order $k=2$) of $\mathbb{N}$ if $x>1?$

Tags: number-theory, combinatorial-number-theory, erdos-conjecture

I know that there are many unanswered questions and conjectures when it comes to [additive bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_basis) (of order $k=2$) of $\mathbb{N}.$ However, for the question I have in mind, I think it *should* be elementary to prove it, but I am having trouble doing so.

> Conjecture: $\ A_x:= \{ \left\lfloor x^n \right\rfloor: n\in\mathbb{N}\ \}\ $ is **not** an
> additive basis (of order $k=2$) of $\mathbb{N}$ if $x>1\
>  ?$

This is probably very easy to show for "large" values of $x$ like $x \geq 1.3:\ $ all you have to do is write a program and find the least integer $q$ that causes failure, i.e. there does not exist $p_1,\ p_2 \in A_x\ $ such that $p_1 + p_2 = q.$ But how to show this for **all** $x>1,$ in particular, like for $x= 1.00000001 ?\ $

I imagine the proof should include the fact that, given  $ j,\ \exists\ N\ $ such that $\left\lfloor x^{n+1} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor x^{n} \right\rfloor > j\ \forall\ n\geq N.\ $ Or perhaps we need to use some stronger statement? Or is this problem not solved? I feel like it should be solvable with elementary methods, using the fact that $A_x$ becomes sparse as $n$ gets very large...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X>10$. We find an upper bound of the sets:

$$
[A_x + A_x]_X :=\{ n+m\leq X  \ | \ n,m\in A_x \},$$

$$
[A_x]_X:=\{ n\leq X \ | \ n\in A_x \}.
$$

The elememts of $[A_x+A_x]_X$ are determined by pairs of elements of $[A_x]_X$, and we have $|[A_x]_X|\leq C \log_x X$ for some absolute constant $C>0$.

A crude upper bound is therefore $|[A_x+A_x]_X|\leq (C\log_x X)^2$.

Then natural numbers up to $X$ represented by a sum of at most $2$ elements of $A_x$ is at most
$$
(C\log_x X)^2+ C\log_x X.
$$

This is smaller than $X$. Thus, almost all (asymptotic density $1$) positive integers are not the sum of at most $2$ elements of $A_x$.